# assembly - get symbolic label from char array?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

Yeah, I'm trying to achieve something like

`__asm__(jmp label;);` where `label` should be replaced by the value of a string held in memory (field of a struct).

Is there a way to do this (or something similar that allows me to jump to a position determined at runtime)?

**Update**
`dlsym` that @Jester suggested looks promising I am now trying to find out how to use it.

If I try the following (gcc flags `-Wall -std=c99 -m32 -ldl`)

```
#include <stdlib.h> //malloc
#include <stdio.h> //printf
#include <stdint.h> //uint32_t
#include <string.h> //strlen,strdup,...
#include <dlfcn.h> //dlsym

void test(){printf("Hello World\n");}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    //this works
    __asm__(
        "call test;"
        );

    //I'd like this to have the same effect
    char *label = "test";
    void *handle = dlopen(NULL,RTLD_NOW);
    uint32_t loc = (uint32_t)dlsym(handle,label);
    __asm__(
        "call %0;"
        :
        :"rm"(loc)
        );

}
```

I get

> Hello World
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Depending on environment, you can use `dlsym` or `GetProcAddress` to get the address of a symbol, then you can jump to it through a pointer.

Comment: C labels aren't valid symbols in the compiled code, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @Jester dlsym looks promising, thank you ... but how DO I use it? (see edit above)

Comment: You forgot to link `-ldl`. Also, you don't even need assembly for this, it is plain C function pointer. You segfault because calling a function may destroy some registers as per the calling convention. If you use a function pointer the compiler will know about this. Otherwise you will have to list them in the asm as clobbers.

Comment: @Jester Forgot it had to be added at the END of the compilation command. But humour me, how would I do this if I needed to do it in assembly? Obviously the snippet above is just to try this thing out.

Comment: @Jester Nope, listing the registers as clobbers doesn't seem to get rid of the segfault.

Comment: The asm should look something like `"call *%0" :: "rm" (loc) : "eax", "ecx", "edx", "memory"` and you need to add `-rdynamic` compiler flag otherwise you get a `NULL` pointer ;)

Comment: @Jester I love you. Thanks a lot. Do you want to elaborate so I can accept it as an answer?

Comment: Note that you don't need the `asm` statement. You can use `((void (*)()) loc)();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The asm should look something like `"call *%0" :: "rm" (loc) : "eax", "ecx", "edx", "memory"` and you need to add `-rdynamic` compiler flag otherwise you get a `NULL` pointer ;) – Jester

Of course, calling functions from inline asm is *hard* to get right, especially for 64bit.  Also, calls that the compiler/optimizer can't see could lead to invalid link-time interprocedural optimizations.

**It's so much easier and better to use a C function pointer**.